# Upload file to virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

I have a web application with a page. The page has a functionality to upload a file.
I have deployed the application on two different servers in IIS7. Both these hosting have a virtual directory pointing to the same physical directory.
Here I am unable to save the posted file in the virtual directory using `Server.MapPath`.

Is there any sophisticated technique to handle such situation to achieve this functionality?

Comment: are you managing the IIS over a VM or a decicated server using remote desktop?

Comment: Yes IIS on VM on AMzon EC2.

Comment: are you using some sort of load balancer?

Comment: yes with session stickyness on

Answer (score 0):

Well  I'd suggest you 2 scenarios:

1. Share a folder/resource beetween those servers (assuming that
   those servers are in the same LAN), then create app key in the
   web.config and this key will contain the path of your shared
   resource something like //Server/Folder, use this value instead of server.mappath at the time you
   save the file in the server
2. If you have a load balancer share a folder of your main node and
   then use the that path in your secondary node something like
   //server/folder that route will save the image in the main node, then
   set up a replication rule from your main node and the secondary the
   configuration of this rule could vary depending on your needs it
   could be an update to the seconday node every 5 minutes for example.

you may create a virtual directory but the purpose for this will be only for displaying the images.

that worked for for me some time ago, it's not a fancy solution but it does the job.